# Запустить команду через n-ное время

Tags: php, cron, crontab

Реализовал у себя на сайте алгоритм выполнения снапшотов. Работает следующим образом: при запросе робота одной из поисковых систем алгоритм проверяет дату создания файла снапшота. Если файл устарел (с момента создания прошло 30 дней), то PHP запускает командой `exec()` NodeJS-скрипт, который обновляет файл снапшота. Проблема в том, что на создание снапшота Нода тратит 3-5 секунд, что не нравится роботу вот совсем. Поэтому единственный способ это исправить, который я смог придумать, это отдавать роботу текущий снапшот, после чего запустить асинхронное отложенное выполнение скрипта. То есть, просто вернуть роботу снапшот (удовлетворив его требование к скорости загрузки страницы). После чего сделать запись в crontab, мол, нужно выполнить команду на выполнение снимка страницы такого-то числа в такое-то время от имени пользователя www-data. Теперь вопрос: во-первых, умеет ли crontab выполнять команды не только с определённым интервалом, а в заданное время и дату? Во-вторых, выполнит ли crontab задачу под пользователем www-data? И в-третьих, может ли crontab удалять запись после выполнения или придется через php открывать файл, искать там нужную запись и стирать её? Спасибо.

Comment: без потери сути текст вопроса можно сократить раз в пять как минимум. что и рекомендую вам сделать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin стараюсь всегда задавать свои вопросы максимально чётко и развёрнуто, чтобы тот, кто его читает чётко понимал, что и зачем я собираюсь делать, и мог дать мне такой же чёткий и развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

1. умеет ли crontab выполнять команды не только с определённым интервалом, а в заданное время и дату?

   нет, конечно. *crontab* — это формат файла, понимаемый программой *cron*.

   дополнение: формат файла *crontab* позволяет указывать время, день недели, день месяца, месяц.
2. выполнит ли crontab задачу под пользователем www-data?

   см. предыдущий пункт.

   с дополнением: программа *cron* работает обычно от имени пользователя `root`, следовательно может запускать процессы с понижением привилегий.
3. может ли crontab удалять запись после выполнения?

   см. первый пункт.

   с дополнением: нет, в функциональность программы *cron* не заложено **никаких** манипуляций с файлами формата *crontab*.
4. или придется через php открывать файл, искать там нужную запись и стирать её?

   гораздо лучшим решением будет периодический запуск вашего скрипта, который будет выполнять необходимую работу (со снапшотами, или чем вам там ещё требуется).