# Добавление новых задач (cron)

Tags: php, cron

Подскажите реализацию следующей задачи. 
Требуется выполнение что-то наподобие cron либо же как то добавлять новую крон задачу средствами php на сайт. А именно после того как пользователь оплачивает услугу, требуется добавить задание которое может выполняется с интервалом каждую 1-5-30 мин либо каждый час-пять-десять-24 на выбор пользователя. Использовать while как по мне не лучшая реализация. Что если у меня больше 100 таких заданий на очереди, получится что интервал не будет работать верно. В качестве примера можно взять например сервис динамических обложек для вк, у них там подобное как то реализовано. Ниже пример как это реализовано у letscover.me. Вот требуется подобное.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На сколько я в курсе на крон напрямую влиять нельзя, поэтому, по идее, создается просто задача с нужными параметрами, а крон потом проверяет каждые n-минут, как вариант. Надеюсь, остальные участники поправят меня

Comment: см. [пункт номер 4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826941/178576)

Comment: @DaemonHK можно.

Answer (score 2):

1. программа *crond* (если кратко): выполняет указанную команду в указанное время и отсылает всё, что выдаст команда в *stdout+stderr* на указанный адрес электронной почты.

   всю логику сверх этого целесообразно выполнять внутри вашей программы (скрипта), которая будет периодически вызываться программой *crond*.
2. вам надо в своей программе (скрипте) реализовать планировщик, который и будет определять, что делать и когда (опираясь на информацию, сохраняемую между запусками, например, в базе данных, или файлах, или ещё где-нибудь).

   об отдельных деталях реализации такого планировщика имеет смысл задавать **новые вопросы** с помощью [соответствующей кнпоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

---

схожий вопрос: [Запустить команду через n-ное время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/826913/178576)

Comment: Причем здесь crond если у меня хостинг? Либо я чего-то недопонял?