# Добавление/удаление периодических фоновых задач в Линуксе -- библиотека?

Tags: linux, cron, background, task

Есть веб приложение. И есть bash скрипт, который принимает на вход агрумент.

Нужно иметь возможно добавлять или удалять фоновые периодические задачи, которые делает этот скрипт, принимая на вход разные аргументы. И задавать периодичность.

Всё это через web страницу.

То есть, **что-то вроде cron задач,** только через web страницу, динамически удаляемых и добавляемых и с динамическим временным интервалом.

1) Подходит ли вообще cron для такого рода задач, если я возьму какую-то cron библиотеку, например, на питоне и буду взаимодействовать с кроном через неё из моего веб приложения?

2) Если нет, то что выбрать?

Мне не нужно ничего сложного, нужно простое, бесплатное, надёжное, и в то же время de-facto решение.

Comment: фактически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833346/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin так там ответа нет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично мне нравится [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) для такого рода задач. Но это весьма мощный и навороченный комбайн для выполнения и отслеживания фоновых задач, которые запущены с веб-сайта (так что на счет ничего сложного тут немного мимо). В том числе есть и планировщик и [умеет создавать](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) cron задачи. Написана она на Python и очень хорошо интегрируется с Django (из-за чего у меня и пал выбор на нее). Но думаю, что не проблема прикрутить ее к чему угодно.

Ну а если нужно совсем простое, то почему б не использовать [python-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/)? Решение вполне рабочее будет, это точно. Главное понять, от какого пользователя запускается веб-приложение. Желательно для этого пользователя и править crontab, но также необходимо проверить, что у него достаточно привилегий для выполнение задачи. Если нет - как решение, добавить нужную задачу в sudoers, для повышения привилегий.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял постановку задачи, с *cron* будет вот какая проблема: каждый файл *crontab* жёстко привязан к конкретному пользователю и располагается в его домашней директории. Пока пользователь не залогинился, никто эту *crontab* обрабатывать не будет.

Можно попробовать использовать  */etc/crontab*, в ней есть дополнительная колонка, задающая пользователя, от которого  запускаются конкретные задачи. Однако, я сомневаюсь, что Ваше веб-приложение имеет право редактировать этот файл.

Мне кажется. что самое простое решение - записать в каталог HTTP-сервера  *cgi-bin* некую программулину, которая будет принимать один параметр от HTML-формы (код запускаемого модуля) и делать *fork/exec* для соответствующего модуля.

Comment: блин, ну что проблема создать крон задачу от того же пользователя, от которого веб приложение работает? вы не о том думаете

Comment: `Мне кажется. что самое простое решение - записать в каталог HTTP-сервера cgi-bin некую программулину, которая будет принимать один параметр от HTML-формы (код запускаемого модуля) и делать fork/exec для соответствующего модуля.` -> то есть должен буду каждый час нажимать на кнопку. и так для каждой задачи.

Comment: @Omanokoto  > *Должен буду каждый час нажимать на кнопку. и так для каждой задачи* 


Кто Вам мешает передавать через форму два параметра: код программы, и что с ней надо сделать - включить/выключить ?

Comment: Там нету "включить". Там есть "начать выполнять задачу каждые N часов".

Comment: **Там есть "начать выполнять задачу каждые N часов".** Попробую уточнить:
1) Имеется несколько программ (скажем A.B,C...) которые должны в определённые интервалы T1, T2, T3... запускаться с периодом t1,t2,t3...
2) Для каждой программы составляем крохотный Shell скрипт, который содержит бесконечный цикл, в котором выполняется запуск  этой программы и после её завершения выдерживается пауза tn.
3)  На стороне пользователя  отслеживаются интервалы Tn. В начале и конце каждого интервала заполняется http-форма, в которой указаны код программы и режим: старт/стоп

Comment: 4) CGI-программа, получившая эту форму, разбирает параметры и выполняет анализ pid-файлов и запускает/убивает соответствующий скрипт.

Вроде бы - всё ?

Comment: что за чушь? зачем бесконечный цикл?