# Cron в Laravel 5 (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, laravel, cron

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы задача в Cron выполнялась каждые n минут, причем n может быть от 1 до бесконечности. Это число указывается в переменной в Laravel, и нужно, чтобы можно было ввести любое число и все работало. Как это можно записать в виде Cron выражения (* * * * *)?

Comment: `*/5 * * * *` - каждые пять минут

Comment: 1. причем тут Laravel? 2. @Manitikyl `*/5 * * * *` не сработает для кейса `до бесконечности`, если ТС захочет 200 минут. ТС, почему до бесконечности?

Comment: Вам надо до бесконечности? Мне кажется проще тогда сделать заготовки, чем писать генератор.

Comment: @Manitikyl Ну, не до бесконечности, а, скажем, 90 минут. Я пробовал сделать так, как вы предлагаете, но задания выполнялись через час, а не через полтора

Comment: дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833346/178576

Comment: но если очень хочется именно через крон.... можно с помощью костылей:
например написать скрипт который будет в качестве аргументов принимать 2 переменные "время" и "уникальный id".  с помощью первого аргумента высчитываем когда запланировать задачу в крон. с помощью второго идентифицируем задачу и  при каждом запуске удаляем её из крона +  добавляем новую